# sed match issue in string case with "\<>"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

i using below sed script for remove some block of content which match with

"binding state free;"

string but problem is that in some blocks i have string

" Next binding state free "

and below command consider it as a match and remove it also i dont want to delete "Next binding state free" block plz suggest.

and delete "binding state free" block from input file.

```
  sed -e '/lease/!b;:a;/}/!{$!{N;ba}};{/\<binding state free;\>/d}' file.txt
```

This command i am using but it also remove " Next binding state free "

block data sed consider it as a match because it also contain "binding state free;" string.

```
lease {

    *****some text******
      binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
    lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
    lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state active;
      next binding state free;
      rewind binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
    lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state active;
      next binding state free;
      rewind binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
```

Desired output :-

```
lease {
          *****some text******
          *****some text******
          binding state active;
          next binding state free;
          rewind binding state free;
          *****some text******
          *****some text******
        }
        lease {
          *****some text******
          *****some text******
          binding state active;
          next binding state free;
          rewind binding state free;
          *****some text******
          *****some text******
        }
```

Comment: Is it always at the beginning of the line? Use `^binding state free;`

Comment: In `awk` you can write `/binding state free;/ && !/Next binding state free;/`

Comment: @Barmar no its within a block

Comment: You also want to remove `rewind binding state free`? Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Negative or positive lookbehind in Perl mode?

Comment: Don't tell us what's not working for you as we don't know how *working* is defined for you. Just tell us your example input data the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/lease {/{:a;N;/}/!ba;/^\s*binding state free;\s*$/M!p}' file
```

Use the grep-like option `-n` to print only that what is required. Gather up lines between `lease {` and ending with `}`. If any single line in the collection contains `binding state free` and nothing else, do not print the collection.

N.B. Use the `M` multiline flag to tailor the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done when you use [GNU `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) and make use of the value `RS` and `RT`.

> **`RS`** The input record separator. Its default value is a string
>   containing a single newline character, which means that an input
>   record consists of a single line of text. It can also be the null
>   string, in which case records are separated by runs of blank lines. If
>   it is a regexp, records are separated by matches of the regexp in the
>   input text. (See [Records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records).)
>
> **(gawk extention)** The ability for `RS` to be a regular expression is a `gawk` extension. In
>   most other awk implementations, or if `gawk` is in compatibility mode
>   (see [Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Options)), just the first character of `RS`’s value is used.
>
> **`RT` (gawk extention)** The input text that matched the text denoted by
>   `RS`, the record separator. It is set every time a record is read.

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="lease *{|}" }
     (RT=="}") && (!/\n *binding state free;/)){ print RTO $0 RT }
     {RTO=RT}' <file>
```

This script sets the record separator `RS` equal to `lease {` or `}`.
If the `RT=="}"`, then we process the record by checking if the requested string is there. The string itself should read `"\n *binding state free;"` This means it is on a single line with only spaces in front of it. If this string is not in the record, print it with the previous and new record separator `RTO` and `RT`.

This outputs:

```
lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state active;
      next binding state free;
      rewind binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state active;
      next binding state free;
      rewind binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
```

If you want to do this in `sed`, I would take the approach slightly different.

```
sed '/lease {/ {:a;N;/}/!ba;/\n *binding state free;/!p; };d;' <file>
```

1. read a full record with `/lease {/{:a;N;/}/!ba;`
2. process the record with `/\n *binding state free;/!p`
3. delete the pattern space `d`

This outputs (slightly differently spaced than `awk`):

```
   lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state active;
      next binding state free;
      rewind binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
    lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state active;
      next binding state free;
      rewind binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
```

Comment: sed -e '/lease {/ {:a;N;/}/!ba;/\n *binding state active;/!p; };d;' file.txt       i am trying to run this but this is not working @kvantour

Comment: @Vijay Could you please define : not working. I just tried it again and it works perfectly on my system. The only things I can imagine are the fact that you might have tabs in your original file.

Comment: This might work `sed '/lease[[:blank:]]*{/ {:a;N;/}/!ba;/\n[[:blank:]]*binding state free;/!p; };d;' <file>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can do it in sed but the thought terrifies me. I would recommend an awk script:

```
# match start of block
$1 == "lease" {
    n = 1
    should_print = 1
}

# save every line in the buffer
{
    buffer[n++] = $0
}

# unset the print flag if text is matched
/^[[:blank:]]*binding state free;[[:blank:]]*$/ {
    should_print = 0
}

# match end of block
$1 == "}" && should_print {
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        print buffer[i]
    }
}
```

Testing it on your input:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
    lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state active;
      next binding state free;
      rewind binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
    lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state active;
      next binding state free;
      rewind binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
```

If you're happy with the output, you can overwrite the input using the standard method:

```
awk -f script.awk file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: i want to delete that data from the input file

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to modify the original file.